# How to efficiently extract specific subsets of list elements in Python

Tags: python, performance, list

I have a a length N list of floats called`vals` and a length N list of 0s and 1s called `bits`. I want to extract two lists: the elements of `vals` that correspond to the 0s in `bits`, and the remaining elements that correspond to the 1s in `bits`. I'm currently doing:

`valsbits = zip(vals,bits)`

`els0 = [v for v,b in valsbits if b == 0]`

`els1 = [v for v,b in valsbits if b == 1]`

but there must be a better way. Also, I'm doing this for many different `bits` vectors, so there may be a clever way to do this entire operation.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: I get the feeling it's not the most efficient solution.

Comment: You should measure its performance to be certain that it is inefficient before taking steps to change it. However, nothing about this strikes me as inefficient at all.

Comment: I have. One thing that strikes me as inefficient is that once I know which elements of vals correspond to the 0s in bits, I know which elements correspond to the 1s, so I shouldn't need to do the whole O(N) walk again.

Comment: O(N) + O(N) = O(N). You don't save anything complexity-wise by only iterating once.

And as mentioned, you really should benchmark if performance is the issue.

Comment: In worst case analysis yes, but in reality I'd like to only do N operations if I can avoid doing 2*N operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.compress`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress), which yields the elements that correspond to true in the selector.

However this would require to duplicate the `bits` and invert a copy to select the elements for the zeros, which would end up with:

```
from operator import not_
true_values = list(compress(sequence, bits))
false_values = list(compress(sequence, map(not_, bits)))
```

---

I believe using a simple `for` loop would be easier and faster, since it does a single iteration:

```
true_values = []
false_values = []
for bit, val in zip(bits, values):
    if bit:
        true_values.append(val)
    else:
        false_values.append(val)
```

---

Just as a curiosity, here are some micro benchmark with the various solutions:

```
In [12]: import random

In [13]: value = 'a' * 17000

In [14]: selectors = [random.randint(0, 1) for _ in range(17000)]

In [15]: %%timeit
    ...: true_values = [v for v,b in zip(value, selectors) if b == 1]
    ...: false_values = [v for v,b in zip(value, selectors) if b == 0]
    ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.56 ms per loop

In [16]: %%timeit
    ...: true_values = []
    ...: false_values = []
    ...: for bit,val in zip(selectors, value):
    ...:     if bit:
    ...:         true_values.append(val)
    ...:     else:
    ...:         false_values.append(val)
    ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.87 ms per loop

In [17]: %%timeit
    ...: res = {}
    ...: for val, bit in zip(value, selectors):
    ...:     res.setdefault(bit, []).append(val)
    ...: true_values, false_values = res.get(1, []), res.get(0, [])
    ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 3.73 ms per loop

In [18]: from collections import defaultdict

In [19]: %%timeit
    ...: res = defaultdict(list)
    ...: for val, bit in zip(value, selectors):
    ...:     res[bit].append(val)
    ...: true_values, false_values = res.get(1, []), res.get(0, [])
    ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.05 ms per loop
In [26]: %%timeit  # after conversion to numpy arrays
    ...: true_values = values[selectors == 0]
    ...: false_values = values[selectors == 1]
    ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 344 us per loop
In [31]: %%timeit
    ...: res = [[], []]
    ...: for val, bit in zip(value, selectors):
    ...:     res[bit].append(val)
    ...: true_values, false_values = res
    ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.09 ms per loop
In [34]: from operator import not_

In [35]: %%timeit
    ...: true_values = list(compress(value, selectors))
    ...: false_values = list(compress(value, map(not_, selectors)))
    ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.44 ms per loop
```

Obviously `numpy` is much faster then the rest, *assuming* that you can replace the python lists with numpy arrays.

It seems like `itertools.compress` is the fastest non-3rd-party solution, at `1.44 ms`.  The second fastest is the naive `for` with an `if-else`, at `1.87`, with other solutions taking slightly more than `2 ms`.

Increasing the number of elements the only changes I see is that the Jon Clement's `defaultdict(list)` solution and newtower's `[[], []]` solution become *marginally* faster than the naive `for`+`if-else` (like`2%` faster at `500000`). `compress` is still 30% faster than the others and `numpy` is still about 4x faster than `compress`.

Does this difference matter to you? If not(and profile to check whether it is a bottleneck!) I'd simply consider using the more readable solution, which is pretty much subjective and up to you.

---

A last remark on the timings I've obtained:

Even though both `compress` and your double list-comprehension iterate over the list twice, one is the fastest non-3rd party solution, and the other is the slowest. 
Here you can see the difference between a "python-level loop", or "explicit loop", versus a "C-level loop", or "implicit loop".

`itertools.compress` is implemented in `C` and this allows it to iterate without much of the intepreter overhead. And as you can see this makes a huge difference.

You can see this even more in the `numpy` solution, which also performs two iterations instead of one. In this case, not only the loop is "at the C level", but it also completely avoid calling python APIs to iterate over the arrays, since `numpy` has its own C data-types.

This is pretty much a rule *in CPython*: to improve performance try to replace explicit loops with implicit ones, using built-in functions or functions definined in C extensions.

Guido van Rossum is well-aware of this, try to read his [An Optimization Anecdote](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str.html).

you can find another such example in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840451/python-string-comparison-pointing-to-the-result) SO question(disclaimer: the accepted answer is mine. I've exploited bisection search and string equality(-> the C-level built-in) to obtain a solution faster than a pure-python linear search).

Comment: `compress()` is only half a solution.  It won't return the `false_values`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I believe you did *not* read the code I wrote that uses `compress`. I just double checked on ipython and it *does* return the elements that correspond to `0`s and `1`s correctly.

Comment: I commented on the first version of your answer.  I'd suggest `map(operator.not_, bits)` instead of the list comprehension to improve performance.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I was looking for. I did the benchmarking before I asked the question (hence the question) and using numpy arrays yielded a huge speedup. Thanks for all the benchmark comparisons and the pointer to ``compress``.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `numpy` arrays for better performance:

```
els0 = vals[bits == 0]
els1 = vals[bits == 1]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I ended up doing. Sped up my application a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following (or just use a `collections.defaultdict(list)`):

```
res = {}
for val, bit in zip(vals, bits):
    res.setdefault(bit, []).append(val)
zeros, ones = res.get(0, []), res.get(1, [])
```

It only scans the list once, and groups on more than true/false values, but does require auxiliary storage for the new lists.

Comment: Looks like `res` should be a `defaultdict(list)`.

Comment: +1 I was about to post this one.(You can also use defaultdict)

Comment: Yup - was in the mood to not include imports :)

Answer (score 0):

```
[val for idx, val in enumerate(values) if bits[idx]]
```

will get you the subset of values matching the `1`s. To get a list with the two subsets (0 and 1s), you could write

```
true_vals, false_vals = [[val for idx, val in enumerate(values) if bits[idx]==bit] for bit in [0, 1]]
```

or

```
true_vals, false_vals = [[val[0] for val in zip(values, bits) if val[1]==bit] for bit in [0, 1]]
```

Comment: What about a nested list comprehension like in my second example ? No one seems to avoid doing the same thing twice (that is, writing one line per bit value)